# Countplot with log yscale

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm sure this is trivial for you guys. I would like to have a seaborn countplot, with ordered x-values and log y-values. It all works, except when I try to do `set_yscale` the chart-blocks disappear - all axis still get painted, but the data in it goes away. here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(18,14))
ax.set_yscale('log')
g = sns.countplot(x='country', data=dfn, ax=ax, order = dfn['country'].value_counts().index, palette=flatui)
```

If I comment out `ax.set_yscale('log')` the chart appears again. How can I achieve a log yscale?
thanks a lot

**edit**
as per comment: you can recreate it using a simple dataframe, e.g.:

```
rand = [1,2,3,4,5]
country = ['PL', 'CZ', 'DE', 'CN', 'AN']
d = {'rand':rand,'country':country}
dfn = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @DavidG Not sure how it adds value, but I added instructions regarding how to create a dataframe

Comment: it adds value because it makes it easier for people to try your example and thus more likely that people will try to help, and therefore more likely you will receive a solution

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce your error. Are you using the latest versions of `matplotlib` / `seaborn`?

Comment: @tom fair enough. yup - just updated and retried with same error. I'm using seaborn 0.8.1, matplotlib 2.2.2, python 3.6.4, and jupyter lab

Comment: seems to be a jupyter lab issue, it does show up without it... grml

Comment: When I use your code with `ax.set_yscale('log')`, I get this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHI1I.png